# How do I receive a dto, with a map as one of it's atributes, as a parameter of my controller? (REST API)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

When I try to send it, it show me the "error": "Bad Request",
"trace": "...HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize Map key of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "quoteDate": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate"

The JSON I am sending via postman:

```
{
    "stockId":"test3",
    "quotes":[
        {
        "quoteDate":"2003-05-14",
        "quoteValue":"35.9"
        },
        {
        "quoteDate":"2016-03-28",
        "quoteValue":"55.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

The controller:

```
@PostMapping("/stock/save")
    public void saveQuotes(@RequestBody StockDTO stockDTO) {
        System.out.println(stockDTO.toString());
    }
```

The DTO

```
public class StockDTO {
    String id;
    String stockId;
    Map<LocalDate, Double> quotes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quotes, the data type that should come as per the json string is a List. but was given a Map in the DTO.
The DTO should be ::

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.List;

public class GsonMappingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"stockId\":\"test3\",\"quotes\":[{\"quoteDate\":\"2003-05-14\",\"quoteValue\":\"35.9\"},{\"quoteDate\":\"2016-03-28\",\"quoteValue\":\"55.0\"}]}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        StockDTO stockDTO = gson.fromJson(jsonString, StockDTO.class);
        System.out.println(stockDTO);
    }
}

class StockDTO {
    private final String stockId;
    private final List<Quote> quotes;

    public StockDTO(String stockId, List<Quote> quotes) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
        this.quotes = quotes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StockDTO{" +
                "stockId='" + stockId + '\'' +
                ", quoteList=" + quotes +
                '}';
    }
}

class Quote {
    private final String quoteDate;
    private final Double quoteValue;

    public Quote(String quoteDate, Double quoteValue) {
        this.quoteDate = quoteDate;
        this.quoteValue = quoteValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "quoteDate=" + quoteDate +
                ", quoteValue=" + quoteValue +
                '}';
    }
}
```

PS: Here I'm using Gson library to parse the json string, spring-boot automatically does that (using Jackson library I think!)